# Shared JSON data for php and Javascript/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am writing a validation mechanizm for my website. Some code is used with Javascript and ajax to validate (mostly lengths of) strings. And some other code is used in php on the server side.

Both PHP and Javascript need to use the same vars, say `MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH`.
So that they stay in sync, and save on development time up front.

I was thinking of using JSON.
But after researhing a little I noticed that:

```
$.getJSON("http://myurl.com/vars.json", function(json) {
  alert(json['MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH']);
})
```

for starters, this for some reason won't access a local location as `../includes/vars.json`, and returns 404 for some reason....

1. I was thinking, if I put this in the `$(document).ready(function ()` then all the code would run, but the vars themselves would not have loaded if the network was slow....

Is there a way to simply do something like :

```
var json=parseJsonFromLocalFile("../includes/vars.json");
```

I need this also for the php, but there I think it would be easier using `json_decode()`
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What do you mean by a local file? On the client or server side?

Comment: Oh soryy. I meant the server side. I want the file to be included, and be synchronous with the whole object model. I mean, I want the vars to be included, and only then used, whereas in the example I gave before, the vars might be used without being read due to network latency.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Javascript file instead of a JSON one - just define all your variables in a PHP array, then make a PHP file with contents like:

```
var config = <?php echo json_encode($config); ?>;
```

and load it like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/vars.php"></script>
```

(`vars.js` would be a better name, but would require that your server knew to process *.js files as PHP.)

This will load your variables synchronously, and gets them into the global scope more easily than an asynchronous JSON load.

Comment: That's a great approach, only that I need the same php file serve the php side as well. That means that when I require_once("vars.php"); It would not compile with the var config = part.

Comment: I meant:    use a GET method and set the code accordingly ? <?php
if($_GET['selector']=='javascript')
echo 'var json= ';
if($_GET['selector']=='php')
 echo '$json = ';
if (($_GET['selector']=='javascript') || ($_GET['selector']=='php'))
  echo'{"MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH":"12","BOX_COLOR":"#254ff3"}';

Comment: @Ted - If I were you, I'd define the configuration variables as an array in PHP, in some centrally located `includes/config.php` file. Then when you need to use it in PHP, just include the `config.php` file in your code (no deserialization from JSON necessary); when you need to use it in JS, include it at the top of the script I detail above and `json_encode` it.

Comment: @Ted - also, not sure what you mean about this not being a GET request. Loading a JS file with a `script` tag does indeed send a GET request to the server. But I think the querystring-based switch you propose is unnecessary here.

Comment: Hi, nrabinowitz, thanks for the help. I am uncertain as of how to include an external js inside an existing js file. It's like in C++ where you need those declarations or variables centralized...

Comment: You shouldn't need to include one JS file inside the other - just use `script` tags to include them both in your page. `script` tags load synchronously, so you can depend on earlier scripts being loaded before subsequent ones (unlike `$.get` and other AJAX functions, which use asynchronous requests where you can't depend on the order).

Comment: You mean use the HTML includes in order... I was constantly thinking of embedding a JS inside a JS!! Thanks!

Comment: Is this the acceptable way of sanitizing client-side and server-side ?

Comment: It sounds good to me - it keeps the configuration variables in one place, and uses two-layer validation, which I like - the Javascript provides a better UI, because the feedback doesn't require reload, but the server side is necessary for security.