# Share config in php with javascript + ajax (json) in usage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, config

I am trying to share a config.inc.php in php with javascript. It works, but not with ajax... there is always the "error-function" called. Is there any way to share the config file with an working ajax?

I am using it in an apache cordova project, with bootstrap and jQuery.

Here is a part of my index.html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="config.inc.php"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            console.log(config_url);
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: config_url,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "param=no",
                    success: function(html){
                       doSomething();
                    });
                    }, error: function(e){
                        alert(e); //always an alert :/
                    }
               });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Here is my config.inc.php:

```
<?php
global $config;

$config["url"] = "http://192.168.1.Y/fetchdata.php";
$config["db"]["host"] = "localhost";
$config["db"]["database"] = "myDatabase";
$config["db"]["username"] = "root";
$config["db"]["password"] = "";
$config["db"]["port"] = null;
$config["db"]["socket"] = null;

?>
var config_url = <?php echo json_encode($config["url"]); ?>; //if i remove this line, ajax will work and call the "success part".
```

And finally the last file "fetchdata.php" for database connection:

```
<?php
// Allow access via php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Load configuration
require 'config.inc.php';
global $config;

$sqlconn = mysqli_connect($config["db"]["host"], $config["db"]["username"],
    $config["db"]["password"], $config["db"]["database"], $config["db"]["port"],
    $config["db"]["socket"]) or die(mysqli_error());

$dataquery = mysqli_query($sqlconn, "SELECT * FROM table_profil");

$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($dataquery)) {
    array_push($arr, array("key" => $row->key, "value" => $row->value));
}
print_r(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

I used XAMPP for testing. The output is

> var config_url =
>   "http://192.168.1.Y/fetchdata.php";[{"key":"size","value":"150"},{"key":"color","value":"green"}]

Without the ''var [...] .php";'' output, it will work... But I liked to share the config.

Comment: This may be the exact reason god created [YAML](http://yaml.org/)

Comment: What is the actual error that is outputted?  You might want to try console.log(e) and copy & paste that somewhere (rather than using alert)

Comment: And it looks like you're mixing javascript with PHP in your config.inc.php code that you're calling with AJAX.  The AJAX call is expecting a valid JSON type (as defined in your calling AJAX), but you are returning HTML at best, but probably something invalid.  Try changing dataType:'HTML' or remove the "var config_url" from the PHP file and echo a pure "json" string.

Comment: I logged it and the following line is red... looks like hes expecting json and not something else... . is there a way to share the config without an output? responseText: "var config_url = "http:\/\/192.168.1.237\/fetchdata.php";[{"key":"size","value":"150"},{"key":"color","value":"green"}]"

Answer (score 0):

you used javascript var in php without `<script>` tag? How come?  use

```
<script>
     var config_url = '<?php echo json_encode($config["url"]); ?>';
</script>
```

instead of

```
var config_url = <?php echo json_encode($config["url"]); ?>;
```

with that way you can pass config_url with javascript but your ajax will not work .. cause ajax not work through servers so you can't use "http://192.168.1.Y/fetchdata.php" in your ajax url .. in your ajax url just use  url:'fetchdata.php', and check you link to its path

Comment: There is something similar in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726118/shared-json-data-for-php-and-javascript-ajax and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Comment: I always get an error with <script...>...</script>. He doesn't like the first "<" in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mohamed-yousef and Michael, I solved it with a part of your answers. You shown me the error and gave me hints for the solution :).

Ted wrotes the solution in [Shared JSON data for php and Javascript/Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726118/shared-json-data-for-php-and-javascript-ajax) . I use a "GET"-Param for supporting javascript. Because my "fetchdata.php" won't have any javascript, I use it without the param => no javascript output if not needed.

My index.php includes the config with a "js" parameter; looks like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="config.inc.php?js"></script>
```

... and my "config.inc.php" looks like

```
<?php
global $config;

$config["url"] = "http://192.168.1.Y/fetchdata.php";
....

if (isset($_GET["js"])) {
    echo
    '
        var config = [];
        config["url"] = "' . $config["url"] . '";
    ';
}
?>
```

No changes in "fetchdata.php".

This solution is working for me. Thanks everybody!

Comment: A friend told me to specify the header in "fetchdata.php" with header("Content-Type: application/JSON");